# Increase Matlab code speed

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, parfor

Is anyone able to help me increasing the speed of the code below, it is taking too long. Regards.

```
limits(1) = 3.2;    
limits(3) = 3.6;
x = ones(426,1);   
y = ones(426,1);
BandWidth = 20;
height = 586;
width = 896;

dmap = zeros(height, width);
parfor  jj = 0 : width - 1
    myTemp = zeros(1, height);
    xi = limits(1) + jj;
    for ii = 0: height - 1
        yi = limits(3) + ii;
        myTemp(ii+1) = sum( exp(-((x - xi).^2 + (y - yi).^2)/(2*BandWidth^2)) );
    end
    dmap(:,jj+1) = myTemp';
end
dmap = (1/(sqrt(2*pi)*BandWidth))*dmap;
```

Looking foward hearing some tips.

Comment: Just FYI, this might be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one actually speeds up quite quite nicely using vectorisation (note the use of `bsxfun`). I used the fact that `exp(A+B)=exp(A)*exp(B)` to compute `exp(-(x-xi)^2/(2*BandWidth^2))` separately for `x` and `y`, and then the summation is handled by normal matrix multiplication, another nice trick. You original code ran in ~5.5 seconds on my computer, this code takes ~0.07 seconds. You do lose a little accuracy for `x` and `y` near `3.2` and `3.6`, but the difference is still below `1e-14`. My hunch is that it's due to round-off error between `exp(A+B)` and `exp(A)*exp(B)`.

```
limits(1) = 3.2;    
limits(3) = 3.6;
x = ones(426,1);   
y = ones(426,1);
BandWidth = 20;
height = 586;
width = 896;
xi=limits(1)+(0:width-1);
yi=limits(3)+(0:height-1);
X=exp(-bsxfun(@minus,x,xi).^2/(2*BandWidth^2));
Y=exp(-bsxfun(@minus,y,yi).^2/(2*BandWidth^2));
dmap=Y.'*X/(sqrt(2*pi)*BandWidth);
```

Comment: Good point using the exp() properties. Enough done! Thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

Decrease the dimensions. e.g:

> height = 128; width = 192

The accuracy will be similar but the performance time will be less.

Comment: I'll can try that. Thx Tariq